# How to create re-usable code in iOS for a custom back button

Tags: ios

I have created a custom back button (code below). I've so far been re-pasting this block of code all through my app on every single page. I was wondering if someone could take my code as an example and give me pointers on how to throw this into one centralized location so that I wouldn't have to copy and paste it anymore.

I'm guessing this would go into a custom class .h and .m that I'd create but I'm not exactly sure what to do next as far as what the code itself would look like within the custom files.

```
// Create custom back button

UIButton *backButton      = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage  *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];

[backButton setBackgroundImage:backButtonImage
                      forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[backButton addTarget:self
               action:@selector(backButton)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[backButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:backButtonItem];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably go with a category on `UIViewController`, with an interface like this:

```
@interface UIViewController (MyBackButton)

- (void)installBackButtonWithAction:(SEL)action;

@end
```

The implementation is the code from your question, with `@selector(backButton)` replaced by `action`:

```
#import "UIViewController+MyBackButton.h"

@implementation UIViewController (MyBackButton)

- (void)installBackButtonWithAction:(SEL)action {
    UIButton *backButton      = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIImage  *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];

    [backButton setBackgroundImage:backButtonImage
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [backButton addTarget:self
                   action:action
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [backButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
    UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
    [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:backButtonItem];
}

@end
```

You might call it like this, for example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self installBackButtonWithAction:@selector(backButton)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a subclass of `UINavigationController` and have it be alter the `navigationItem` of any view controller that's pushed Ito its stack to set the custom back button. Then you just create an instance of your custom class instead of your current use of `UINavigationController` and every view controller will automatically get updated.

Answer (score 1):

You could put that code into a [category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) somewhere; given you're setting `self` as the target, `UIViewController might work. But, thats kind of ugly and relies on an assumption that your dismissal action will never change.

Something cleaner that you could do is refactor it a bit so that you create the button by passing in the target (`self`) and dismissal action (`backButton`) and have the category on UIBarButton instead.